# Произвольное выполнение функции/метода класса n раз

Tags: c++

Добрый день! Изучаю с++, интересует выполнение функции произвольное количество n раз из консоли или другого метода.
например есть функции:

```
void func1(){...};
int func2(params){...; return int r;}
```

И я хочу скажем в консоли написав run func1 20 запустить ее на выполнение 20 раз, после нее run func2 10 запустить на 10 и т.д. как можно это сделать?

Comment: Тогда нужен какой-то способ передать в цикл функцию на исполнение, при этом где-то запоминать return если нужно, а вот как это делается?

Comment: Смотрите - если функции у вас имеют у вас одинаковую сигнатуру, то все относительно просто - делаете hasmap из строки и указателей на существующие функции. А потом получив из консоли две переменные строку и число, используете <строку> как ключ хэшмап и вызывает соответствующую функцию <число> раз. Если функции имеют разную сигнатуру - тут все сложней - фактически вам придется написать свой язык, и его транслятор в язык с++.

Comment: @Mirdin, если сигнатуры разные, то всё это делается элементарным свичом или ифами.

Comment: @Mirdin, можно без языка просто расписать все ифами. Сколько я помню, свич не работает со строками в С++.

Comment: @ixSci - если их две или три - то да, я просто предположил, скажем так, негативный сценарий.

Comment: @Mirdin, уточните речь идет про std::map<std::string, (что-то типа указателя)> или какой-то другой структуре? Т.е. вы имеете ввиду создание рефлексии с функциями где соотношение строка-указатель?

Comment: @Ir5666 да std::map<std::string, (ваш КОНКРЕТНЫЙ указатель на функцию)>

Comment: лучше `std::function`, чем указатель на функцию. Если и не со стороны размера, то со стороны простоты и понятности использования.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
int foo(){
    return 4;
}

int bar(int a){
    return a*a;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc < 3) return 1;

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "foo") == 0){ //Выбираем имя функции
        std::vector<int> returnValues; //Вектор возвращаемых значений
        for(int i=0; i<atoi(argv[2]); ++i){
            returnValues.push_back( foo() );
        }
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "bar") == 0){ //Выбираем имя функции
        if(argc < 4){
            std::cout << "Недостаточно аргументов для функции bar!" << std::endl;
        }
        std::vector<int> returnValues; //Вектор возвращаемых значений
        for(int i=0; i<atoi(argv[2]); ++i){
            returnValues.push_back( bar(atoi(argv[3])) );
        }
    }
}
```

Далее, после компиляции (`g++ source.cpp -o myRun`) можно вызывать на исполнение функции из него: `myRun foo 4` - вызовет функцию `foo` 4 раза; `myRun bar 7 3` вызовет функцию `bar` семь раз, передав в параметр `3`.

Если требуется что-то делать с возвращаемыми значениями, то они будут лежать в `returnValues` (разумеется делать с ними можно что-то только внутри программы).

Код не проверял, так что могут быть небольшие синтаксические ошибки.